# Give count for column values python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies in advance that I couldn't create code to generate the sample data.

Here is my data frame, Columns B,C,D,E have appointment dates. I am trying to count the number of dates that exist per row and append that number to Column G without disturbing Columns A and F. Do I need a function? True/False for values then count? Is there a simple way?

```
    A       B           C           D           E           F           G   
0   1       20171021    20171021    20171021    20171021    id_123  
1   2       NaN         20171021    20171021    20171021    id_234  
2   3       NaN         NaN         20171021    20171021    id_345
3   4       NaN         NaN         NaN         20171021    id_456
```

Desired Output

```
    A       B           C           D           E           F           G   
0   1       20171021    20171021    20171021    20171021    id_123      4
1   2       NaN         20171021    20171021    20171021    id_234      3
2   3       NaN         NaN         20171021    20171021    id_345      2
3   4       NaN         NaN         NaN         20171021    id_456      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, use `count`.

```
cnt = df[['B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].count(axis=1)
print(cnt) 
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64

df['G'] = cnt
```

Comment: Maybe I thought too much

Comment: @Bharathshetty You did, but the column slicing was a nice touch, I like it. Will upvote, give me a second :)

Comment: It was inspired by you :)

Comment: Thank you, this was a very efficient solution and worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can sum the not null values i.e `.notnull()` will give the boolean mask. Sum of boolean mask gives the count.

```
df['G'] = df.loc[:,'B':'E'].notnull().sum(1)
```

```
   A           B           C           D         E       F  G
0  1  20171021.0  20171021.0  20171021.0  20171021  id_123  4
1  2         NaN  20171021.0  20171021.0  20171021  id_234  3
2  3         NaN         NaN  20171021.0  20171021  id_345  2
3  4         NaN         NaN         NaN  20171021  id_456  1
```

Comment: Thank you! this was what I was looking for with the True/False, I'll remember 'boolean mask' for next time.